# Why I can't show my arrayList, when I saves her by another Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, bufferedreader, inner-classes

Hello I have a problem to display List from the outside class. I try using public void show() method but the list is empty. I think that the problem is with thread, is this possible ? can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
public class CollectionsOperation
{
    private List<Client> bufferedReaderClientLIst =
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Client>());

    BufferedReader bf = null;

    private static final String fileName = "clients.txt";

    public void bufferedReaderCollection()
        throws IOException
    {
        String line;
        try {
            bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));

            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split(";"); 
                String nameCompany = split[0].substring(2);
                String adress = split[1]; 
                String phoneNumber = split[2]; 
                String emailAdress = split[3];

                Client k = new Client(nameCompany, adress, phoneNumber, emailAdress);
                bufferedReaderClientLIst.add(k); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void runBufferedReader()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new CreateList());
        t.start();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst);
    }

    private class CreateList implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            CollectionsOperation o = new CollectionsOperation();
            try {
                o.bufferedReaderCollection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call `o.show()`

Comment: I have call in another class:public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
  
  CollectionsOperation k = new CollectionsOperation();
 
  k.runBufferedReader();
  k.show();

Comment: Then you should update the code of your question to match the code you are attempting to run. As it is right now, they appear to be different.

Comment: If what you put in the comment is what you are actually using, because the code in `runBufferedReader` is running in a separate thread, the call to `k.show()` is probably happening _before_ your list is populated.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on when and how you begin to call `o.show()`. Since this list is mutable, and asynchroinzed. It will show expected values if you are sure you call `o.show` after `o.bufferedReaderCollection();`

-----------update ---------------
Basically below flow should works for you.

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new CreateList());
t.start();
try{
  t.join();
} catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst);
```

Comment: I have use k.runBufferedReader(); then  k.show(); my program show me empty list []. I want to download the contents of the file to ArrayList, then I want to use this data to another function. I use Thread and I can't get completed listed. Do you have any Idea what i can do more ?

Comment: Your scenario is typical 'asynchronous code'  issue. Your way is wrong, as you cannot force thread to run when you use `t.start()`. An ugly work around is you can use Thread.join() to wait that thread complete before you print. Another way is to use `async-await. You can get help from [this library](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async) though Java language didn't offer this feature like C# or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that your  method `CreateList::run` creates a new instance of  `CollectionsOperation`. So the original objects method `show` will not access the same data as the list that is populated by your `CreateList` class.

Instead you probably want to use

```
        public void run()
        {
            CollectionsOperation.this.bufferedReaderCollection();
        }
```

Alternative is to create a constructor in your `CreateList` with an  `CollectionsOperation`object as argument and use that.

```
public class CollectionsOperation
{
    ...
    public void runBufferedReader()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new CreateList(this));
        t.start();
    }
    ...
    private class CreateList implements Runnable
    {
        CollectionsOperation co;
        public CreateList(CollectionsOperation co) {
            this.co = co;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                co.bufferedReaderCollection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you should also look into thread synchronisation for concurrent access to your list.

Comment: I have try your solution but effect all the time is the same empty list. Console shows me:[]. I change my show() method for this public void show() {  
  synchronized(bufferedReaderClientLIst) {
   Iterator<Client> iterator = bufferedReaderClientLIst.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext())
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
  }
  
  /* System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst); */
 } but then I received nothing

Comment: I suspect you probably need to put in some synchronisation - that your output actually waits for the input to finish. I have seen in another comment you made that you have the `show()` directly after the `Thread.start()` not sure if that is the final structure of your code - then why use a Thread? If it is not then do you want to show at some point the current content of the list while it is still reading in the data or just have at the end the output? E.g do something else and then wait for the input to finish?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am using the thread because I do not want the error loading data to affect the operation of the user interface. I would like to receive the downloaded data from the file into arrayList, and then use them by adding additional methods: sorting, searching, etc. My problem is that I can't use the data because after executing the method in the thread I lose access to it. I will try to use CompletableFuture is this good way to resolve this problem in your opinion ?

Comment: I have no experience with `CompletableFuture` but I suspect you will have similare problems. What I would suggest is to expand your bufferedReaderCollection() method with something that does all the other stuff you want to do on the data and then update GUI from there. If you use a swing-gui use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.